# SQL alias gives "invalide column name" for Group By

Tags: t-sql

I have a problem trying to make an alias for new column and using it in GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT TOP 100 Percent
count(id) AS [items_by_day],    
(SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [date]))) AS [date_part]
FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[MyTable]
GROUP BY DAY([date]), MONTH([date]), YEAR([date]), date_part
```

I get the following error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'date_part'.
```

How is it possible to solve the problem?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I checked the part with datediff, it works as I expected. The problem is that this code worked before, but when I added aggregation function and group by clause, it started showing the error described in the original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## How about a subquery?

See my [demo at sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ff7b8/8)

```
Select  Count(*) as nrOfRecords, sq.[items_by_day], sq.[date_part] 
From (
    SELECT TOP 100 Percent count(id) AS [items_by_day]
      ,(Select Dateadd(dd, 0, Datediff(dd, 0, [date]))) AS [date_part]
    From  [MyTable] 
    Group By id, date
) as sq
Group by sq.[items_by_day], sq.[date_part]
```

The part [`(SELECT DateAdd(... DateDiff(...))`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ff7b8/11) seems to return the plain date. Can you explain what i am missing?

Comment: Glad i could help. Could you do me a favour and give me a hint  what dateadd datediff does?
Thanks

Comment: The idea was to get a date part from the datetime field and then to use this field for further aggregation. The datetime I work with contains precise datetime stamps, but I wanted to aggregate the data daily. By the way, is there any more effecient and convenient way to do that? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry out of my head i have no idea for effecient date handling - but why not put stackoverflow to the test: formulate a new question - for example: How to effeciently calculate Day differences from date fields in SQL Server?

Comment: I think there is also a branch with similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629534/getting-the-date-out-of-a-datetime-field-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a column alias in a GROUP BY, aliases are for display, unless when the alias is in a subquery, in this case , it becomes the column name.